# How to iterate over rows in pandas data frame, with reference to two column at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, average

I have a df as seen below, I want to calculate average from speed_InMeterS column, with respect to time, and lane. In other word, at time 1 I need average speed for lane x.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oZY8.png)

I tried, but I can only make reference to one column (time). I'm expecting to computer the average speed for each lane at time T.

Comment: Where is the df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add the df,
If I understand correctly, you want to have the average speed_InMeterS  for each  time and lane. for that you don't need to iterate. you should use groupby:

```
time_lane_mean_speed = df.groupby(["time", "lane"]).agg({"speed_InMeterS": "mean"})
```

Please elaborate any more details for a better answer

Comment: Yes, I want have average speed for each time and lane. Thank you for your quick response and help.

Comment: Sure. In general, when working with data you shouldn't iterate over rows. Learn about vectorization. It will save you a lot of computation time